# Tasks.Task.Run: port from C# to F#

Tags: f#

I am looking at some legacy C# code like this:

```cs
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        _logger.LogException(LogLevel.Error, message, exception);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    });
```

I created the following F# code but the Thread.Sleep is not getting hit:

```
    Tasks.Task.Run(fun _ -> logger.Log(LogLevel.Warn, message)
                            Thread.Sleep(500))
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?  I need maintain the method's signature.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is normally where you would use a asynchronous workflow. If you need to keep the function returning a Task, you can do this:

```ml
let someFunc (message : string) : Task =
    async {
        logger.Log(LogLevel.Warn, message)
        Thread.Sleep(500)
    } |> Async.StartAsTask :> Task
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is working, I am just getting an exception:

> `System.AppDomainUnloadedException`: Attempted to access an unloaded `AppDomain`. This can happen if the test(s) started a thread but did not stop it. Make sure that all the threads started by the test(s) are stopped before completion.

Comment: Once I changed the test to use the task.Wait, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Task expressions in F# now make it easier to consume and return tasks.

```
let someFunc (message:string) : Task = 
        task {
            logger.Log(LogLevel.Warn, message)
            Thread.Sleep 500
        }
```